# Is jsPDF dependent on jQuery or can you use pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I have a client that can not use jQuery for any reason, is jsPDF dependent on jQuery or is there a way to specify use pure javascript?

Comment: If you're talking about https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js it's pure javascript.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield yes thats what I was talking about, I get this error in this file and line number which refers to jQuery:

`jspdf.plugin.from_html.js     ->     424`

Comment: The top of that file says `jsPDF fromHTML plugin. BETA stage. API subject to change. Needs browser, jQuery` so that file in particular has a jQuery dependency for the plugin. So if you need that plugin you need jQuery, if you don't then you don't need it and you don't need to link to that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of jsPDF has removed the dependence on jQuery, the version I used is v1.5.3. You can view the demo on CodePen:

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/martinhong91/pen/xoLRwV)

```html
<!-- load only jsPDF -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// Use it now!
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

var cmd = document.querySelector('#cmd');
cmd.addEventListener("click", function () {   
    var contentContainer = document.querySelector('#content');
    doc.fromHTML(contentContainer.outerHTML, 15, 15, {
        'width': 70,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```